# Best way to refactor/implement isLoading from inside a StatefulWidget into a separate class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a working "TestScreen" widget that gets and displays user's location coordinates. While _isLoading is true, it shows a loading wheel, and that state variable is controlled inside functions declared inside this StatefulWidget.

```
class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  bool _isLocationPermissionGranted = false;
  Position _currentPosition = const Position(
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      accuracy: 0,
      altitude: 0,
      heading: 0,
      speed: 0,
      speedAccuracy: 0,
      timestamp: null);
  bool _isLoading = false;


  Future<void> _checkLocationPermission() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    final LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      setState(() {
        _isLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } else if (permission == LocationPermission.always ||
        permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
      setState(() {
        _isLocationPermissionGranted = true;
      });
      await _getCurrentLocation();
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    try {
      final Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      );
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error getting location: $e");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Location Tracking'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              _isLocationPermissionGranted
                  ? 'Location Permission Granted'
                  : 'Location Permission Denied',
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('Latitude: ${_currentPosition.latitude}'),
            Text('Longitude: ${_currentPosition.longitude}'),
            
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _checkLocationPermission,
              child: Text('Request Location Permission'),
            ),
            
            _isLoading
                ? Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine, but I want to put the location-related variables and functions in a separate LocationService class. However, I'm then unable to simply update the _isLoading bool using setState anymore.

**TLDR: What is the industry-standard way to refactor this code so that I can have a separate class file for all things related to LocationService AND still control the isLoading variable in the TestScreen widget?**

Comment: I did create a LocationService class and got it to work somewhat, but the TestScreen state didn't get updated when variables inside LocationService were updated. I tried using Provider package to manage state changes but it started to look really messy and unncessary as I had to create another class called "LocationState" and call it inside runApp in main, (and it still ended up not working properly). Is this the only way? Or is there another common model to do this?

Comment: Riverpod.  Riverpod deals nicely with streams, futures, and synchronous data, including a hierarchy of dependencies, and the abilty to trigger rebuilds. **That's** the industry standard way.

Answer (score 1):

I tried my best to produce the minimal code. I believe it's better to separate the UI and the service. Now, it's looking more cleaner & nicer.

You may notice that I wrote an additional few lines of code for you in service. In checkLocationPermission(), I tried to handle all possible outcomes. And in getCurrentLocation(), I tried to enhance & tweak.

And in part of UI, you can see how I manage the loading thing. I improve the code by myself. Now, it works flawlessly.

> main.dart

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:myapp/location_service.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Flutter Demo",
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const TestScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestScreen> createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  LocationService instance = LocationService.instance;
  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Location Tracking"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: isLoading
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    instance.isLocationPermissionGranted
                        ? "Location Permission: Granted"
                        : "Location Permission: Denied",
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text("Latitude: ${instance.currentPosition.latitude}"),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text("Longitude: ${instance.currentPosition.longitude}"),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: isLoading
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                            isLoading = true;
                            setState(() {});

                            await instance.checkLocationPermission();

                            isLoading = false;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                    child: const Text("Request Location Permission"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> location_service.dart

```
import "dart:async";
import "dart:developer";

import "package:geolocator/geolocator.dart";

class LocationService {
  LocationService._();
  static final LocationService instance = LocationService._();

  bool isLocationPermissionGranted = false;
  Position currentPosition = const Position(
    longitude: 0.0,
    latitude: 0.0,
    timestamp: null,
    accuracy: 0.0,
    altitude: 0.0,
    heading: 0.0,
    speed: 0.0,
    speedAccuracy: 0.0,
    floor: 0,
    isMocked: true,
  );

  Future<void> checkLocationPermission() async {
    final LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    switch (permission) {
      case LocationPermission.denied:
        break;
      case LocationPermission.deniedForever:
        break;
      case LocationPermission.whileInUse:
        isLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        await getCurrentLocation();
        break;
      case LocationPermission.always:
        isLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        await getCurrentLocation();
        break;
      case LocationPermission.unableToDetermine:
        break;
    }
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      currentPosition = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
      log("LocationService : Success : ${currentPosition.toJson()}");
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      log("LocationService : Failure : ${e.message}");
    }
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using Riverpod for state management and the code got surprisingly clean, but yes your way would be the way to go without using any package.s Thanks a bunch

Comment: You don't need all those breaks in Dart 3.  The lint should have told you. :)